# Is it possible to duplicate mouse and keyboard events across two different Iframes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have two Iframes with dynamic content embedded within a webpage meant to compare the difference between them. To do this I'd like to one iframe to duplicate or mirror the mouse and keyboard events in the other.

Is this possible?

Comment: What exactly do you do in these iframes? + Do you control both?

Comment: These two frames get their content from a src url. The goal is to compare their differences. To aid in that goal it would be nice to mirror clicks in both when testing functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Use querySelectorAll to assign same event for two elements

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".a, .b");
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log("clicked");
  });
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure this would apply to this use-case. As iframe content would be dynamic, I cant declare explicit event bindings like you are suggesting. Or if I do it can only be to the iframes themselves. Which may not, for example, simulate a interaction with a dropdown in the iframe from a click in another.